# What are the proper rules for the root Directory Directive

Tags: apache2

I have an `Ubuntu 14.04` with an `index.php` at Document root, which is `/var/www/` and at a subfolder called `blog`, that contains, well, my blog.

I think I've foolishly changed the directives and I cannot remember which the default ones were.

So, what would be the rules under the Directory directive for `/var/www` at the file `/etc/apache2/000-default.conf`?

Should it be something like this:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Ubuntu 14.04, the default site configuration for Apache no longer contains such a section. Here's the content of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

A modification within the `VirtualHost` definition that worked for me was:

```
  DocumentRoot "/var/www"
  <Directory "/var/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride Options
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

(`AllowOverride` can `None`, but in this case I needed some options in `.htaccess`.)

Comment: I am on `14.04`, so I might have added the directory directives myself (all in all, the file except my additions is the same with the one you've posted).  So, where should I add them?

Comment: You can add them in the virtualhost definition. I figured you're only looking to restore the default.

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted :)